# Titanium: Android device token without Cloudpush

Tags: android, titanium, google-cloud-messaging

Is there anyway to get device tokens without using Cloudpush modules. All I'm interested in is getting tokens and store onto my server and then I can push notification to registered devices.

I have tried to use it Cloudpush module from this link
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.CloudPush

I followed these steps:

1) First Step : 
     Open this link https://developers.google.com/console/ 
     than login with you account. Create a new project

```
i) "Creating a Google API Project", 
ii)"Enabling the GCM Service"
iii)"Obtaining an API Key"
```

Image snap link : http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-AKAcUDtW0gg/UlK8rcpqUQI/AAAAAAAACuI/aq89OFZc2C4/s1600/all_steps.png

2) Second Step : 
      Click on this link https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
     You can found you project that you already created.
     Just Click on that and you found the Example: Project Number: 91060sdsdgsd

3) Third Step : 
    Now next step open this url https://my.appcelerator.com/apps
    Login with your appcelerator account where you want to configure this vcm.
    Click on your project than at the top side there are two option (Production/Development).
    Click on Development. Now the main menu box will open in that there is 2nd (Second) tab            click on that.
    Now you found in that page Android Push Configuration
    please fill this both fields
    i) Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) API Key:
    ii)Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) sender ID:

However all I'm getting is Failed receiving GCM SenderId.

Comment: Which titanium sdk you are using?

Comment: I'm using 3.4.0.GA, and my device has android 4.4.2 installed on it

Answer (score 1):

As you already know the process to get keys/etc, so I wont rewrite it.

You asked to fetch the device token without Cloudpush , yes it can be done and you have to use a **GCM module** for this process.

Following info will be helpful in using module :

- You can view the module's info at [GCM Titanium](https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-).
- The **zip file** of module is at in [dist folder](https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-/tree/master/dist) ( use latest version of zip ).
- Example to use module is under [example folder](https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-/tree/master/example).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks turtle, I followed all steps and now m getting [INFO] :   module gcm is => [object Object]
[INFO] :   Registering... Nothing happens after that, code is not entering in success or error block.